# Simple php insert and database display not working

Tags: sql

I'm trying out this code but nothing happens when I run it and at the same time I can't display anything from the database? any suggestions?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Forename']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Surname']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);

$sql="INSERT INTO 'customer1' ('Forename', 'Surname', 'Email')
VALUES ($Forename, $Surname, $Email)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping table name `customer1` and columns with single qoutes which is wrong.You have to do it using **``** backticks

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `customer1` (`Forename`, `Surname', `Email`)
VALUES ($Forename, $Surname, $Email)";
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with your sql query

```
$sql="INSERT INTO customer1 (Forename, Surname, Email)
VALUES ('$Forename', '$Surname', '$Email')";
```

remove quotes from table and column names and add quotes to all the values

Answer (score 0):

**Add quotes in values if values are string. Otherwise Insert query is always going to fail.**

Try this:

```
$sql='INSERT INTO  customer1  (`Forename`, `Surname`, `Email`)
VALUES ("'.$Forename.'","'.$Surname.'", "'.$Email.'")';
```

Remove other unnecessary quotes from table name and from field name.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the quick responses, but nothing seems to work so far, I think that my script isn't cnnecting to the database at all, an have no idea what to do about that.

Comment: please check host name, username and password. Except these, I think nothing is wrong in abovr code